# JS - how come charAt() not working in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, console.log

I'm brushing on Javascript functions and for loops, and can't understand why the below code won't run correctly. Is the charAt() function deprecated? I thought the function would iterate over each string in my `cars` array...

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++){
    console.log(i.charAt(0))
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean `cars[i].charAt(0)`? `i` is a number, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

you are using position `i` with `chaartAt()` but you need is value in that position `cars[i]`

change `i.charAt(0)` to `cars[i].charAt(0)`

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var i;

for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i ++) {
    console.log(cars[i].charAt(0));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`i` is your loop index, so it has no method `.charAt()`. You probably meant to do `cars[i].charAt(0)`.

This fetches the string from the `cars` array at index `i`, and then calls `.charAt(0)` on that string to get the first character in the string.

This can also be written `cars[i][0]`, unless you need to support really, really old JS engines like the one in IE6.

---

An alternate way, available in the newest JS engines, would be to use a `for of` statement. This lets you avoid manual indexing.

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];

for (const car of cars) {
    console.log(car[0]);
}
```

This assigns each member of `cars` to `car` (per iteration), which makes things a little cleaner. I also went ahead and used `[0]`, since any engine supporting `for of` statements will also support string indexing.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var i;

for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i ++) {
    console.log(cars[i].charAt(0));
}
```

you were not referring to the index of the element you wanted to refer to, charAt(0) won't work for numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over each of the strings in the array you would not need charAt() at all. Is this what you are looking for or do you just want the first character of each string as you iterate through the array?

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++){
console.log(cars[i])
}
```

This will output each string to the console, not just the first character.